# DocumentFilter wont detect and handle a paste/insert from a webpage (html)

Tags: insert, paste, jtextpane, documentlistener, documentfilter

Has anyone found a way to allow for a *DocumentFilter* to detect pastes from web browsers into a *JTExtPane*?

I've noticed that it will catch pastes of text or text from a console into a *JTextPane*, but on windows when  something from a webpage is pasted into a *JTextPane* the *DocumentFilter* does not detect a insertString() or a replaceString().

An interesting thing to note is that a *DocumentListener* will catch the paste from a webpage to a *JTextPane* and detect it as a insertString().

*I've tested this on Linux and Windows.*

If anyone has a work around or can shed some light as to why this is happening I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because neither `insertString()` nor `replaceString()` are called. If HTML content is found in clipboard (not plain text) `HTMLReader/HTMLParser` parse it creating appropriate `Document`'s `Elements`.